# Nvim: Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":

Tags: lua, neovim, autocommand

I have been using nvim for a couple months now and 90% of the time everything works smoothly.

Sometimes when I open nvim on my laptop (the same config works fine on my PC) I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: Error executing lua: /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype
.lua:25: BufReadPost Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocommands for "*": Vim(append):Error executing lua callback: ...cal/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders
/init.lua:139: attempt to index field 'loaded_fts' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...cal/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders/init.lua:139: in function 'load_lazy_loaded'
        ...fergus/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/plugin/luasnip.lua:87: in function <...fergus/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/plugin/luasnip.lua:86>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </home/fergus/nvim-linux64/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: ...cal/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders/init.lua:139: attempt to index field 'loaded_fts' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...cal/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/lua/luasnip/loaders/init.lua:139: in function 'load_lazy_loaded'
        ...fergus/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/plugin/luasnip.lua:87: in function <...fergus/.local/share/nvim/lazy/LuaSnip/plugin/luasnip.lua:86>
```

I have tried removing all autocommands in my nvim config but I end up getting a different error instead, I'm not sure what is causing the issue.

[My nvim config (lua)](https://github.com/FergusJJ/nvim-config)

Edit:

Sometimes I also get:
`Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Autocommands for "*"`

When starting nvim

Comment: Run this command `:TSInstall vimdoc` it helped me get rid of error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

As Abdul Basit commented:

Run this command `:TSInstall vimdoc` fixes this issue.